# Mostrando nome do link através da url

Tags: php

Fiz esse código abaixo com tudo não esta funcionando da forma que eu quero, preciso que o código faça seguinte: ao invés de apresentar o numero de posição na variável `$verificar`, mostre o texto buscado da variável `$nomeServidor` ao invés da posição, alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

No caso existem alguns servidores que eu verifiquei que tem no caso palavras quase iguais tirando algumas letras diferenciadas como os servidores `https://my.pcloud.com/` e `https://cloud.com/`, no caso estou tendo problemas na hora de efetuar a busca com URLs semelhantes pois se em `$nomeServidor` tiver `cloud` pesquisa tanto `cloud` como `pcloud`, como posso corrigir isto?

```
function nomeServer ($servidorNome) {
    $urlservidor = $servidorNome;
    $nomeServidor   = 'google';
    $verificar = stripos($urlservidor, $nomeServidor);
    echo $verificar;
} 

echo nomeServer ('https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B7zY19LCJa8XeXZtWklZbFBEVG8&export=download');
```

Preciso que o *script* pegue o nome da *URL* usando a referencia colocada em `$nomeServidor` de forma exata ai caso o resultado esteja certo mostre valor *verdadeiro* caso contrario valor *falso*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expressão regular. No caso abaixo você procura exatamente pela palavra em questão. A função te retorna um Array() com os resultados.

```
$re = "/(\\W|^)google(\\W|$)/"; 
$str = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B7zY19LCJa8XeXZtWklZbFBEVG8&export=download"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 3):

Não está claro que informação você quer obter da *URL*, mas segue abaixo algumas alternativas.

### Função [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php)

Utilize está função para obter os componentes que compõem uma URL, como o [*scheme*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme), *host*, porta, usuário, diretório (após o sinal  de`?`), etc.

Veja um exemplo:

```
$url = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B7zY19LCJa8XeXZtWklZbFBEVG8&export=download";
echo "<pre>" . print_r(parse_url($url));

// Resultado:
// Array (
//    [scheme] => https
//    [host] => docs.google.com
//    [path] => /uc
//    [query] => id=0B7zY19LCJa8XeXZtWklZbFBEVG8&export=download
// )
```

Para obter somente o *host*, faça:

```
$url  = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B7zY19LCJa8XeXZtWklZbFBEVG8&export=download";
$site = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

echo $site . "\n"; // docs.google.com
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/1sct6E)

### Funções [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) e [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php)

A função `substr` tem como objetivo retornar determinada parte de uma *string*, ela recebe três argumentos, o primeiro é a *string*, o segundo é a posição inicial da parte que você quer retornar, e o terceiro indica a quantidade de caracteres a serem retornados a partir do segundo argumento.

Já a função `strpos` encontra a posição numérica da primeira ocorrência de uma *agulha* num *palheiro*.

- <sub>**Nota**: Utilizaremos o resultado desta função para usar como o segundo argumento na função `substr`.</sub>

Código:

```
function extrairHostPorIndice($url){
    // Extraí tudo que estiver depois das duas primeiras barras "//"
    $depois  = substr($url, strpos($url, "//") + strlen("//"));

    // Extraí tudo que estiver antes da primeira barra "/"
    $antes = substr($depois, 0, strpos($depois, "/"));

    // Retorna o resultado
    return $antes;
}
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
$url  = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B7zY19LCJa8XeXZtWklZbFBEVG8&export=download";
$site = extrairHostPorIndice($url);

echo $site . "\n"; // docs.google.com
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/wETJDP)

### Função [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strstr.php)

Está função retorna parte de uma *string*, o primeiro argumento é o *palheiro*, o segundo é a *agulha* (ponto de referência), o resultado será a parte que estiver depois do *ponto de referência*, se você passar o terceiro argumento como `true`, o resultado será a parte que estiver antes do *ponto de referência*.

Código:

```
function extrairHostPorReferencia($url){
    // Extraí tudo que estiver depois das duas primeiras barras "//
    $depois = strstr($url, "//");

    // Elimina os dois primeiros caracteres, que são "//"
    $depois = substr($depois, 2) . "\n";

    // Extraí tudo que estiver antes da primeira barra "/"
    $antes  = strstr($depois, '/', true);
    return $antes;
}
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
$url  = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B7zY19LCJa8XeXZtWklZbFBEVG8&export=download";
$site = extrairHostPorReferencia($url);
echo $site. "\n"; // docs.google.com
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/wssXYv)

**Nota**: Se não for essa a informação que você quer obter, diga nos comentários.